# not checking for Id in FLS checks before query and DML

Tags: security, salesforce-id, security-review

I am not checking for Id in FLS checks before query and DML. Is this a security review vulnerability in salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

Id does not have FLS. This is answered here [Do we need to check FLS for Record Id field in apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234009/do-we-need-to-check-fls-for-record-id-field-in-apex)

By the way, “should you” do access checks? Depends on which context & sharing keyword the apex is run in.
Read about them here :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_perms_enforcing.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm